# How to throw exception messages inside the multiprocessing code?

Tags: python, pycharm, multiprocessing

For example, I am using multiprocessing pool to process files:

```
 with Pool(5) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(self.process_file, zip(files, repeat(channel)))
```

When an exception occurs inside the function `process_file`, the exception message indicates that it occurs at the `pool.starmap` line, but not the actual place inside `process_file` function.

I am using PyCharm to develop and debug. Is there a way to change this behavior? The current error message doesn't give the correct position of the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Multiprocessing transfers the errors between processes using the pickle module, but pickle doesn't know how to preserve the tracebacks of exceptions by default.

I found [`tblib`](https://pypi.org/project/tblib/) to be a very convenient way to address this shortcoming. Based on [this example](https://pypi.org/project/tblib/#pickling-exceptions-together-with-their-traceback-and-chain-python-3-only) I suggest you try adding this code to the main module of your code:

```py
from tblib import pickling_support

# all your setup code

pickling_support.install()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # your pool work
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception has the original exception info but PyCharm is not ferreting it out.

Assuming there are no PyCharm configuration options to enhance its ability to ferret out all the exception information, and not just the outer exception as your are seeing, you need to programmatically extract it out.

For good in-program error handling, you probably want to do that anyway. Especially with sub-processes, I very often will catch Exception and log it and re-raise if not considered handled (depends), or if I catch a specific exception I'm expecting and consider it handled, I won't re-raise it.

Note, it's not only PyCharm showing the outer exception... I see the same thing with other tools.

Below will show you the original problem (see "Line 7" below) and re-raise. Again, re-raising or not is really context dependent so below is just an example. But the point is that the exception you are seeing has more data that PyCharm by default is apparently not showing you.

```
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool
import traceback

def process(a,b):
    print(a,b)
    raise Exception("not good")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as pool:
        try:
            results = pool.starmap(process, zip([1,2,3,4,5], repeat('A')))
        except Exception as ex:
            print("starmap failure:")
            for error_line in traceback.format_exception(ex, ex, ex.__traceback__):
                error_line = error_line.strip()
                if not error_line:
                    continue
                print(f"  {error_line}")
            raise # re-raise if we do not consider this handled.
```

Gives me this output:

```
starmap failure:
  multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\...\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "...\starmap_exception.py", line 7, in process
    raise Exception("not good")
Exception: not good
"""
  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\starmap_exception.py", line 12, in <module>
    results = pool.starmap(process, zip([1,2,3,4,5], repeat('A')))
  File "C:\Users\...\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 372, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\...\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  Exception: not good
```